# /login returns HTTP Status 404 Spring security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-rest

I am configuring security in my Application. I am using Spring-4.0 security
below is my security configuration

```
   <http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" />
    <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />
    <logout />
</http>

<!-- Connect the custom authentication success handler -->
<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="com.zertones.system.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
<!-- Using default failure handler -->
<beans:bean id="myFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

<!-- Authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="temporary" password="temporary" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="userPass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Enable the annotations for defining the secure role -->
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

> web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

> restAuthenticationEntryPoint

```
@Component("restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint
{

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException
    {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

but when i tried to hit http://localhost:8080/CollegeApp/j_spring_security_check or http://localhost:8080/CollegeApp/login it gives me 404 status

Comment: do you have a login.jsp file?

Comment: no i am using rest call

Comment: curl -i -X POST -d j_username=temporary -d j_password=temporary -c ./cookies.txt http://localhost:8080/CollegeApp/login here this is what i am trying